# KDE. Notification window width

Tags: kde, notifications, notification-area

1) Some application send notification "Completed very long task #125"

2) Press triangle in systray

3) Open "Notifications" window

I see just small part of my notification message. Like "Completed very... 8 min ago"

I want see full message. Make this [notification] window width bigger.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

(Also, I know about the possibility to see it somewhere in system logs. I don't like that way in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

In file `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.private.systemtray/contents/ui/ExpandedRepresentation.qml`

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
...
Item {
    id: expandedRepresentation

    //set width/height to avoid an useless Dialog resize
    width: Layout.minimumWidth
    height: Layout.minimumHeight
    Layout.minimumWidth: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth / 3 //units.gridUnit * 24
    Layout.minimumHeight: units.gridUnit * 21
```